# cron job not executing the php script

Tags: php, cron

today i learned about cron jobs, i opened SSH and followed along with the 1and1 cron job tutorial, the tutorial file and instructions worked fine however when i did the same steps but with my own PHP script it didnt work, below is the cron job command i used

```
* * * * * /usr/bin/php /path-to-webspace/heal.php
```

and below is the heal.php file, this file works as intented without cron as i tested it beforehand

```
<?php

include('onedirectorydown/database_connection.php');

$resetAllHealth = "UPDATE users SET Health = Health + 1000";
$executeAH = mysqli_query($dbc, $resetAllHealth);

?>
```

i want it to execute every minute as im just testing it to see if it works but it doesnt, however the sample in the 1and1 tutorial worked and i basically followed along exactly, i just the file contents to whats in the heal.php

could someone tell me why it is not executing?

Comment: What user is the cronjob running as? Does it have permissions to execute the script?

Comment: i can find the username but i cant see what permissions it gives me however i did execute another script which was the 1and1 tutorial file and that managed to work

Comment: Try adding `MAILTO=your@address.com` to your crontab. You should receive the entire stdout and stderr via email and use the output to diagnose why the PHP script does not run.

Comment: did it and got email saying X-Powered-By: PHP/4.4.9
Content-type: text/html

<br />
<b>Fatal error</b>: Call to undefined function: mysqli_connect() in <b>/onedirectorydown/database_connection.php</b> on line <b>8</b><br />

Answer (score 1):

Common issues with CRON jobs are that required include files aren't working properly. For example:

```
include '/database.php';
```

Might try to include `/var/www/database.php` when executed from the browser, but might try to include `/home/username/database.php` when executed from the CRON job of the appropriate user.

Consider replacing calls with

```
include $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/database.php';
```

and seeing if that helps.

Answer (score 0):

Looking at your last comment, maybe you don't have the right mysqli extension installed into the php.ini file for cli (usually under /etc/php5/php.ini).

Remember: "apache" scripts and "command line" scripts have two different php.ini files.

Comment: how would i install the one i need?

Comment: Usually there's a .deb package for that, but I don't know which Linux flavour you are using. Googling a bit could help